# Map not works in map v2

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I want to get map location by name.

But map is not showing lcoation. My code is given below:

```
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
    if (googleMap != null)
        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);           
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
     List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("Ferozepur Rd Lahore", 1);
     if (addresses.size() > 0) {
         int lat  = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6);
         int longt  = (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6);

     p = new GeoPoint(lat,longt);
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, longt);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longt)).title("Hello world"));       

         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

     }
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But it is showing me this result:

[image]

Comment: may be your location value is zero.check your latitude and longitude value.

Comment: Without Location Showing you Code is working fine?? mean map is showing oe not??

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and longitude itself you didnt shown.code is incomplete.However Use Mapview balloons.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons